# Denylist client IP in Azure Application Gateway

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-application-gateway

We are using Azure Application Gateway for our site, and we are getting few people **scraping** our site. We want to block their IP at gateway level, as we don't want to configure the same blocks in every web service.

We can not find the way of blocking IPs using only the gateway or its virtual network. Had anybody the same problem and can illuminate our path?

Comment: Can you try setting up NSG rules at subnet level, assuming that all webservices are in same subnet. Or you can attach same nsg to all subnets, if thats an option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could deploy Application Gateway in a virtual network. If so, you will have a dedicated subnet for this Application Gateway. This subnet can only contain Application Gateways. You could [associate an NSG to this subnet.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/tutorial-filter-network-traffic#associate-network-security-group-to-subnet) If so, you could restrict inbound and outbound traffic from this Application Gateway subnet via inbound or outbound security rules in NSG. In this case, you could add an inbound security rule to backlist your clients' IP.

Refer to [DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-faq#are-network-security-groups-supported-on-the-application-gateway-subnet), Note:

> Network Security Groups (NSGs) are supported on the application
>   gateway subnet with the following restrictions:
>
> Exceptions must be put in for incoming traffic on ports 65503-65534
>   for the Application Gateway v1 SKU and ports 65200 - 65535 for the v2
>   SKU. This port-range is required for Azure infrastructure
>   communication. They are protected (locked down) by Azure certificates.
>   Without proper certificates, external entities, including the
>   customers of those gateways, will not be able to initiate any changes
>   on those endpoints.
>
> Outbound internet connectivity can't be blocked.
>
> Traffic from the AzureLoadBalancer tag must be allowed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I did, but I didn't found the documentation about the ports to open (I only found the ports for v2 SKU), so I needed to open all of them :-/

Comment: Yes, you need the ports 65200 - 65535 open for the v2 SKU.